# Update the position of a single resource in a sequence while conforming to REST?

Tags: api, rest, architecture

Given the following sequential collection of books:

**Request:** `GET /favorites/books/`

**Response:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "50"
        "title": "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy by Douglas Adams",
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "51"
        "title": "1984 by George Orwell",
        "position": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "52"
        "title": "Dune by Frank Herbert",
        "position": 3
    },
    {
        "id": "53"
        "title": "Slaughterhouse 5 by Kurt Vonnegut",
        "position": 4
    },
    {
        "id": "54"
        "title": "Ender's Game by Orson Scott Card",
        "position": 5
    }
]
```

What would be the best means of updating the position of a book resource in the collection?

**Request:** `PUT /favorites/books/54`

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "id": "54"
    "title": "Ender's Game by Orson Scott Card",
    "position": 2
}
```

1. Should the API automatically change the position of the other book resources back by 1?

   - If this is the case how does the client know the new "sequence state" of the entire list? Should I return the entire list in response after PUTting just 1 book?
2. Should I only allow the collection to be updated and not the individual books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restful way would be to consider the list of positions as the resource.

You would then do something like :

```
PUT /favorites/books/positions
[ 
  { "book_id" : "50", "position" : "1"},
  { "book_id" : "54", "position" : "2"},
  { "book_id" : "51", "position" : "3"},
  ...
]
```

Comment: That makes sense. I really hate having to deal with another resource here, but fundamentally position is relevant for the collection even though it can be a property of the book. You can't update position on one book without affecting 1 other. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I assume you meant for that to be an [array] instead of an object?

Comment: Scaling this to large collections could be difficult. The API needs to sort out what happens when not every object is present in the PUT request. Also, The client may need to send every object back. However, this is still the best solution I've seen, and I think this difficulty is fundamental to RESTful architecture.